# React proptypes doesn't give warning when object type has missing element inside

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a very simple web to demonstrate my question.

App.js

```
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react'; 
import Playaround from './playaround/Playaround';

function App() {
  const person = {
    name: "joe",
    age: 52,
    random: {
      text: "some random stuff"  
    }
  }

  return <Playaround {...person}/>

}

export default App;
```

Playaround.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useReducer, useContext } from "react";
import Proptypes from 'prop-types';


export default function Playaround({name,age,random}) {


    return <div>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <h1>{age}</h1>
        <h1>{random.text}</h1>
        <h1>{random.missing}</h1>
    </div>
}

Playaround.propTypes = {
    name: Proptypes.string.isRequired,
    age: Proptypes.number.isRequired,
    random: Proptypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

If name, age, or random is not defined, the console would give proper warnings. However, in "Playaround.js", when I put {random.missing}, although the object random doesn't have the key "missing", the console doesn't give any warning. If important data is missing, it would be hard to configure. How can I deal with it and let the console show the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PropTypes.shape` and define the shape of `random`

```js
Playaround.propTypes = {
  name: Proptypes.string.isRequired,
  age: Proptypes.number.isRequired,
  random: PropTypes.shape({
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    missing: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for